# Customize Ant script and Subversion Commands and Scripts for automating a process

Tags: eclipse, svn, ant, eclipse-plugin, svncommit

I want to do the following by customizing an Ant script or Ant XML and SVN commands.
I have four projects in an Eclipse workspace. I'm using Eclipse Indigo and I'm using Java EE.

I have four projects a,b,c,d of Java web applications and Java web services.
I want to automate the following process:

```
1.Get update from svn for All a,b,c,d project.
2.clean all four project.
3.Build all four project.
4.make jar of project d and export into lib of project b.
5.Build b project.
6.make jar of project c and export into lib of project a.
7.Build a project.
8.Make ab.war archive of project a and b and put into specified location(i.e. c:\xyz\)
9.Then I want to commit this ab.war archive to a particular svn location or tag it (for read-only).
```

How I can accomplish that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First read this [Ant tutorial](http://ant.apache.org/manual/tutorial-HelloWorldWithAnt.html).  Then see my comments below...

> 1.Get update from svn for All a,b,c,d project.
>
> 9.Then I want to commit this ab.war archive to a particular svn location or tag it (for read-only).

You can try [SVNAnt](http://subclipse.tigris.org/svnant.html) or just make external calls with [`<exec>`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html).

> 2.clean all four project.

[`<delete>`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/delete.html)

> 3.Build all four project.
>
> 5.Build b project.
>
> 7.Build a project.

[`<javac>`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javac.html)

> 4.make jar of project d and export into lib of project b.
>
> 6.make jar of project c and export into lib of project a.

[`<jar>`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/jar.html), [`<copy>`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/copy.html)

> 8.Make ab.war archive of project a and b and put into specified location(i.e. c:\xyz)

[`<war>`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/war.html), [`<copy>`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/copy.html)

Comment: Thankyou :) If i stuck & need help some where then i will ask here.

Comment: I have completed this task plus some additional work using dos shell. ;) Thanks once again wspider :)

Comment: Can you please tell me how to generate "Apache axis web service client" using ant? is there any ant task available which takes wsdl etc of webservice & generate its client,I tried searching but unable to find out. ?

Comment: @AsadYarKhan [This](http://axis.apache.org/axis/java/ant/ant.html) maybe?  I've never used it.  Might be worthy of a new question.

Comment: I have done using this tutorial http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/jst/components/ws/1.0/tutorials/WebServiceAntTask/WebServiceAntTask.html